# Почему возникает ошибка nan(ind)?

Tags: c++, c, математика, матрицы, линейная-алгебра

Пытаюсь привести матрицу к треугольному виду.
На входе

```
4
10 23 17 44 25
15 35 26 69 40
25 57 42 108 65
30 69 51 133 95
```

// на входе принимается размер матрицы

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int m = n + 1;// размер матррицы вместе с векторм b [n][m]
    double a[4][5];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            cin >> a[i][j];
    }


    ////проверяем, что первый элемент первого столбца не равен 0
    for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
            if (a[i][0] == 0) {
                for (int y = 0; y < m; y++) {
                    int z = a[i][y];
                    a[i][y] = a[i + 1][y];
                    a[i + 1][y] = z;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            cout << a[i][j] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }//вывели матрицу

    //cout << endl;
//приводим к треугольному виду
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        {
            if (a[i][i] != 0) {
                
                 for (int k = i; k < n - 1; k++) {
                
                    float s = a[k + 1][i] / a[k][i];
                
                    for (int x = i; x < m; x++) {
                        float c = a[k][x] * (-1) * s;
                        a[k + 1][x] = a[k + 1][x] + c;
                    }
                 }
                
            }
        }
    }


 

    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            cout << a[i][j] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }//вывели матрицу

}
```

Comment: Цифра 4 в вопросе куда относится? Поправил оформление матрицы до человеческого, но, куда деть 4, не понял

Comment: 4 это в случае с динамическим массивом. Здесь для простоты использовал матрицу с заранее известным размером. Ax=b где А матрица размера 4.

Comment: Добавьте ещё текст ошибки полностью, пожалуйста.

Comment: На выходе получается вот так 10 23 17 44 25 
                                                    0 0.5 0.5 3 2.5 
                                                    -nan -nan -nan -nan -nan 
                                                    -nan -nan -nan -nan -nan

Comment: Укажите это в самом вопросе с помощью кнопки править

Answer (score 5):

Потому что вы делите на 0.

Запишите

```
assert(a[k][i] != 0);
```

перед

```
float s = a[k + 1][i] / a[k][i];
```

и убедитесь в этом сами...

Что и неудивительно - ведь матрица

```
10 23 17  44
15 35 26  69
25 57 42 108
30 69 51 133
```

вырожденная, ее определитель равен 0...

P.S. Что-то странный у вас вложенный цикл

```
for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
```

нет? `i` во вложенном цикле скрывает `i` из внешнего, да и дальнейшее вызывает сомнения... `int z = a[i][y];` тоже как-то не комильфо :) - зачем `double` до `int` обрезать?
Но главное - какой смысл в проверках **до** преобразований? Ведь именно в их процессе очередной опорный элемент может стать нулевым! Возьмите простую матрицу, типа

```
1  1
1  1
```

и вручную убедитесь, что первая ваша проверка работает, но уже после первой итерации преобразований вы получите нулевую вторую строку - и никаких проверок такой неприятности у вас уже нет.

Comment: Насколько я знаю, assert убрали из библиотеки. Нет?...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Почему же? http://eel.is/c++draft/cassert.syn